# A regular expression to match a single character followed by numbers and ends with 'c'

Tags: php, regex

I need a regex for the following pattern:

a single character from [e-g] followed by one or more numbers that ends with character 'c'.

for example
e123f654g933c
 expected result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => e123
            [1] => f654
            [2] => g933
        )

)
```

or

e123f654g933ce99f77g66c 
expected result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => e123
            [1] => f654
            [2] => g933
        ),
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => e99
            [1] => f77
            [2] => g66
        )

)
```

I tried using the following but I don't know what to do with 'c' part.
I used this ([e-g]{1}[0-9]{1,}c)+ but it fails.

```
$subject="e123f654g933ce99f786g776c";
preg_match_all('/[e-g]{1}[0-9]{1,}/', $subject, $match);
print '<pre>' . print_r($match,1) . '</pre>';

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => e123
            [1] => f654
            [2] => g933
            [3] => e99
            [4] => f786
            [5] => g776
        )

)
```

thanks.

Comment: You should match the title and description of your question to the code and examples. And to you need to add the spaces after matching the data?

Comment: post the final expected result

Comment: Are these input strings reliably formatted or might there be "sub-sequences" that don't qualify?  Are we validating, extracting, or both?

Comment: @mickmackusa The input strings are formatted , actually this is part of an encoding method to generate the invoice numbers for an e-commerce website my problem solved thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't manage to generate your multi dimensional output array via a single regex function call.

Code ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/G1lT5))

```
$strings = [
    'e123f654g933c',
    'e123f654g933ce99f77g66c'
];

foreach ($strings as $string) {
    var_export(
        array_map(
            function($v) {
                return preg_match_all('/[e-g]\d+/', $v, $out2) ? $out2[0] : [];  // split the groups by string format
                // or return preg_split('/\d+\K/', $v, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
                // or return preg_split('/(?=[e-g])/', $v, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

            },
            preg_match_all('/(?:[e-g]\d+)+(?=c)/', $string, $out1) ? $out1[0] : []  // split into groups using c
            // or explode('c', rtrim($string, 'c'))
            // or array_slice(explode('c', $string), 0, -1)
            // or preg_split('/c/', $string, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
        )
    );
    echo"\n\n";
}
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
 array (
    0 => 'e123',
    1 => 'f654',
    2 => 'g933',
  ),
)

array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'e123',
    1 => 'f654',
    2 => 'g933',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'e99',
    1 => 'f77',
    2 => 'g66',
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are looking for

```
[e-g]\d+
```

---

This needs to be matched and extracted in `PHP` like so...

```
<?php

$strings = ['e123f654g933c', 'e123f654g933ce99f77g66c'];

$regex = '~[e-g]\d+~';

foreach ($strings as $string) {
    if (preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches)) {
        print_r($matches[0]);
    }
}
?>
```

---

... and yields

```
Array
(
    [0] => e123
    [1] => f654
    [2] => g933
)
Array
(
    [0] => e123
    [1] => f654
    [2] => g933
    [3] => e99
    [4] => f77
    [5] => g66
)
```

Comment: You are asked to group the output strings into a multi-dim array based on `c`.

Comment: @mickmackusa: Honestly, I found the question vaguely phrased and it hasn't gotten clearer yet.

Comment: I'm not certain about whether validation is actually necessary or if this is purely an extraction task (because the OP is working with reliable input strings).  The expected output is clear enough though.

Comment: @mickmackusa: Fair enough, will think about a single regex solution here.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
'~(?:\G(?!^)|(?=(?:[e-g]\d+)+c))[e-g]\d+~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/49XH1P/1). In short, due to the `(?:\G(?!^)|(?=(?:[e-g]\d+)+c))` part, `[e-g]\d+` will only match when in between 1 or more occurrences of `[e-g]\d+` and `c`.

**Details**

- `(?:\G(?!^)|(?=(?:[e-g]\d+)+c))` - match the end of the last successful match (`\G(?!^)`) or (`|`) the location followed with an `e`, `f` or `g` letter followed with 1+ digits, 1+ occurrences (due to the`(?=(?:[e-g]\d+)+c)` positive lookahead)
- `[e-g]\d+` - an `e`, `f` or `g` letter followed with 1+ digits

[PHP demo](https://ideone.com/WTlbI0):

```
$re = '/(?:\G(?!^)|(?=(?:[e-g]\d+)+c))[e-g]\d+/';
$str = 'e123f654g933c and e123f654g933ce99f77g66c';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
// => Array ( [0] => e123 [1] => f654 [2] => g933 [3] => e123 [4] => f654 [5] => g933 [6] => e99 [7] => f77 [8] => g66 )
```

Comment: You are asked to group the output strings into a multi-dim array based on `c`.

Comment: @mickmackusa No idea what you mean by that comment. `$matches` is exactly what "I am asked to".

Comment: Your output array is single dimensional.  The OP wants multidimensional.

Comment: My friend.  I am failing to communicate to you. Please re-read the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can't easily achieve this with a single RegExp.
The solution is to split the string at the occurrences of 'c', handle the parts separately, and then build the result array:

```
<?php

$strings = [
    'e123f654g933c',
    'e123f654g933ce99f77g66c',
];

foreach ($strings as $input)
{
    print_r(match($input));
}

function match($input)
{
    $result = [];
    $parts  = array_filter(explode('c', $input));

    foreach ($parts as $part)
    {
        preg_match_all('~[e-g]\d+~', $part, $matches);
        $result[] = $matches[0];
    }

    return $result;
}
```

The output will be

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => e123
            [1] => f654
            [2] => g933
        )
)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => e123
            [1] => f654
            [2] => g933
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => e99
            [1] => f77
            [2] => g66
        )
)
```